# How to include barchart into my leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, html, github, leaflet

I found a github code online that helps me to include all sort of charts into my leaflet maps in particular the bar charts. However, I copied the cdn into my main html code and written the code to create the bar chart in another js file called leaflet-barchart.js and it is not appearing on my page. Here is the github page for reference: https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf/wiki  at the bottom page it says to include the cdn files to use the charts which was what I did but still nothing is happening. If there is something that I did wrong do let me know.

```
// HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Map Testing</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <!-- Cdn for jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Event handling of checking of checkboxes -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // This if statement hides any layers from the start
                if($(".leaflet-piechart-icon")){
                    $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").hide();
                }
                if($(".legend")){
                    $(".legend").hide();
                }
                // Shows or hides layers when checkbox is checked or unchecked
                $('input[id="pie-charts"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").show(500);
                        $(".legend").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").hide(500);
                        $(".legend").hide(500);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="bar-charts"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        //$("").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        //$("").hide(500);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="choropleth"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        //$("").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        //$("").hide(500);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="string-lines"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        //$("").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        //$("").hide(500);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Access style.css file in the same folder -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="line line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="pie-charts"> Pie Charts <!-- put onclick="toggleLegend();" in the tag to toggle the legend-->
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="bar-charts"> Bar Charts
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="choropleth"> Choropleth
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="string-lines"> String Lines
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-choropleth.js"></script>
        </div>
        <script src="http://sashakavun.github.io/leaflet-canvasicon/leaflet-canvasicon.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet-piechart.js"></script>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript"></script> -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-dvf/0.3.1/leaflet-dvf.markers.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-d4jm/DxK0vxzigVql4lmwFikmXIlItcko9Me2md/mwI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-dvf/0.3.1/leaflet-dvf.markers.js"
        integrity="sha256-NWe8/8nwSWLS01t+tEKiSi5++ddqxqHp8mDjd8o+fbg="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-dvf/0.3.1/leaflet-dvf.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-VnIRySJ1EB1lyfCsnc/pmkdtdplnEgjEBy08ZoZHJcQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-barchart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

// leaflet-barchart.js
var options = {
    data: {
        'dataPoint1': Math.random() * 20,
        'dataPoint2': Math.random() * 20,
        'dataPoint3': Math.random() * 20,
        'dataPoint4': Math.random() * 20
    },
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {
            fillColor: '#FEE5D9',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 20,
            maxHeight: 20,
            displayText: function (value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {
            fillColor: '#FCAE91',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 20,
            maxHeight: 20,
            displayText: function (value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {
            fillColor: '#FB6A4A',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 20,
            maxHeight: 20,
            displayText: function (value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {
            fillColor: '#CB181D',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 20,
            maxHeight: 20,
            displayText: function (value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
    weight: 1,
    color: '#000000',
}
var barChartMarker = new L.BarChartMarker(new L.LatLng(20.594, 78.962), options);
```

Comment: Hi guys, I really need help on this, have been trying to troubleshoot why Ive included the codes but its still not working, i included the cdn codes near the bottom of the html code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `divIcon` and a charting library to achieve the same effect.
 An example: `https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-neumann-d3eh2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark`

```
function drawChart() {
  // Our labels along the x-axis
  var years = [1500, 1600, 1700];
  // For drawing the lines
  var africa = [86, 114, 106];
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  new window.Chart(ctx, {
    type: "pie",
    backgroundColor: ["red", "blue", "purple"],
    data: {
      labels: years,

      datasets: [
        {
          fill: true,
          data: africa,
          borderColor: ["red", "blue", "purple"]
        }
      ]
    }
  });
}

function setupMap() {
  var mymap = window.L.map("mapid").setView([53, 12], 13);
  window.L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    attribution:
      '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(mymap);

  var icon = window.L.divIcon({
    className: "custom-div-icon",
    html: "<canvas id='myChart'></canvas>",
    iconSize: [120, 120],
    iconAnchor: [15, 42]
  });

  window.L.marker([53, 12], { icon: icon }).addTo(mymap);
}

setupMap();
drawChart();
```

and in html

```
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="mapid"></div>
```